# discord.py bot doesnt answer with user's mention

Tags: python, discord, bots

The thing I'm trying to make is a "kiss" command, user types !kiss then bot is supposed to answer by "{user} kisses you ! {author}"
but it does not work

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def kiss2(ctx, target:discord.Member = None):
    if target == None:
        await ctx.send("Tu n'as mentionné personne !")
    
    else:
        await ctx.send(target.mention)
        await ctx.channel.send(" GROS BISOUS {target.mention}, de la part de {ctx.author.mention} !!!!!!!")
        await ctx.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/cony-brown-flying-kiss-love-gif-14132471")```
````

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Hey ! I have not tried anything yet because my python knowledge is terrible. It is something I have been wondering because I also need it at the moment to prevent a raid.
But, I thought of something like : "[bot] checks logs"; if there are more than 3 ban/kicks; [bot] checks the [user] that banned; bans the specified [user]; [bot] sends a pm to [user] saying "You have been banned due to raid prevention." I am sincerely sorry to not show anything that could help you so far.

Comment: You will have to learn the language and write some code, so you can present it here together with a specific problem. You can not expect that we will write the program for you.

Comment: I am not expecting anyone to do anything for me. I want to know if my thoughts were possibly correct

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your else statement, see below

```py
@client.command()
async def kiss2(ctx, target:discord.Member = None):
    if target == None:
        await ctx.send("Tu n'as mentionné personne !")
    
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f" GROS BISOUS {target.mention}, de la part de {ctx.author.mention} !!!!!!!")
        await ctx.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/cony-brown-flying-kiss-love-gif-14132471")
```

You need to add "f" before your {target.mention}, othewise {target.mention} is a string, not a variable.